# How to reload table view with new data

Tags: iphone

I am calling other view controller name "cityState" on button click which has table in it. 
code for calling that view on button click(which has table):

```
[self presentModalViewController:cityState animated:YES];
```

now in this view controller I am loading my table with data, its working fine for first time.
 For example numberofRowsInSection is like:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    SingleTon *s = [SingleTon sharedInstance1]; 
    NSMutableArray *x; 
    rn =[s getRName:x]; 
    NSLog(@"rname : %@",rn); 
    return [rn count];
    [s release];  
    [ss release];  
    [x release];
}
```

I have a button on this view, and on button press I am going back to the view from which I called this cityStae view

```
//code for button click 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now I when I am back on the first view, here I am changing the value of rn (as rn I am using in table view) and calling the table view again with same button click as I did first time, view is called and it is showing with old value of rn and I can see at this time of call NSLog in my numberofRowsInSection is not reached. So the old table with old data is displayed.
My question is **how to show table with new data.**?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `[tableView reloadData];`

*Reference*: [UITableView Class Reference by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

But always make sure that you set the correct **delegate** and **datasource** for your UITableView.

Comment: did the datasource actually changed? did you try (most of the time) tableView.datasource = self;

Comment: I can't see that datasource being actually changed...as on recalling its not going in numberofRowindex method

Comment: so if  the datesource is not changed how should the table be updated (changed)?

Comment: so I am doing anything wrong? as you can see from my code I used singleton class to access my shared variable,( and i know variable is updated) in numberofRowIndex method, but its not going on to that method when I am recalling my view containing table

Comment: Yes, you're doing something wrong. I've given you a correct answer. The problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Could you please guide me..how I should approach in this matter?  You can see from my code what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to say: Before u read the mentioned documentation, u should study basic C and Objective-C. There are several errors in ur Code: x is neither allocated nor initialized — only the name "x" exits. u cannot to anything after a return in a method.

Comment: I dun need x that's why I dun care what it has to do after a return in a method

Comment: releasing is important. u are not releasing, as [... release] will never be called, ur code is wrong and u are missing important things about the programming language u r using. take my advice, study objc from the beginning. If u present code like that on SO, u barely can't expect help, because nobody will be able to tell where to start http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m